# Node.js code/file structure

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a node.js test application that prepends "hello" to a give string.

I have the main file and then a test file:

helloPrepend.js:

```
var helloPrepender = (function() {
    // your code goes here
    function prepend(text){
        return "hello" + text;
    }
}());

// make prepender available via "require" in Node.js
if (module.exports) {
    module.exports = helloPrepender;
}
```

I'm not sure how I'm going about this wrong but it felt wrong defining the prepend function inside a function inside "var helloPrepender"

But also it seems like helloPrependTester is not accessing helloPrepend's function properly.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, but two quick notes,

in

```
var helloPrepender = (function() {
    // your code goes here
    function prepend(text){
        return "hello" + text;
    }
}());

// make prepender available via "require" in Node.js
if (module.exports) {
    module.exports = helloPrepender
}
```

`helloPrepender` is not returning the function.

You should write

```
var helloPrepender = (function() {
    // your code goes here
    return function prepend(text){
        return "hello" + text;
    }
}());

// make prepender available via "require" in Node.js
if (module.exports) {
    module.exports = helloPrepender
}
```

Then generally speaking, this can be simplified to

```
function prepend(text){
    return "hello" + text;
}
module.exports = prepend
```

Or even,

```
module.exports = function (text){
    return "hello" + text;
}
```